# Strange blank line under Bookmarks on Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I don't know how but I got a strange blank line under the Bookmarks on my Safari. It looks like this :

[image]

I tried to look under Safari setting in View or Window, but nothing seems to relate to this. I couldn't find anything on the Internet either. How do I make this strange line disappear?

Comment: Maybe it is an empty toolbar?

Comment: When I right click -> Customize Toolbar, the line doesn't show up and when I restore the default the default toolbar (that doesn't have the weird line), nothing changes.

Comment: it looks like a Tab bar without a tab - try toggling tabs on/off with Cmd/shift/T

Comment: Nope, Cmd-Shift-T doesn't do anything. And tabs appear under the blank.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to fix this.  Go to Preferences in Safari.  Then click extensions and uninstall whatever is there.  It will fix it.  :)

Comment: What extension caused the issue for you?